# Unable to use Github in VSCode

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I keep getting this error when I try to push to GitHub from VScode. I've pushed before to that repository following the exact same steps I am following now and it worked before

> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/github-link/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Timed out

I tried

```
git pull --rebase origin branchname
git push origin branchname
```

But it's still giving me the same error

Comment: Check your network connectivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that maybe you have a problem with your internet connection or your Github credentials. You need to consider that if you are using a firewall it can block Github by default.